# I want two different font sized text children to be at same level from bottom in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using two text widgets in the Wrap widgets whose direction is set to horizontal. I want these two different font sized text children to be at same level from bottom. And don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
   alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: RichText(
     text: TextSpan(
     text: 'Hello ',
     style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
     children: <TextSpan>[
     TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
     TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Comment: you can also achive this using Stack or Expanded widget

Answer (score 0):

put this as the body of the scaffold:

```
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                  textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('text1',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,),),
                    Text('text2',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```